# Client can't see website

Tags: website

A simple temporary landing page:
http://www.carltonforestgroup.com/

Hosted on shared hosing that I control. They control DNS and have pointed to my server IP using an A Record. "www" is pointed to carltonforestgroup.com using a CName.

Client can't see page and receives this message in IE10:

```
This page can’t be displayed
Make sure the web address http://carltonforestgroup.com is correct.
Look for the page with your search engine.
Refresh the page in a few minutes.
Check that all network cables are plugged in.
Verify that airplane mode is turned off.
Make sure your wireless switch is turned on.
See if you can connect to mobile broadband.
Restart your router.
Fix connection problems
```

Everywhere I test the site from is fine including:
http://ismywebsiteupnow.com/en/quicktest.php?action=result&qtid=1118415&r=7939

I just want to check I'm not missing anything and that I can advise them that this is a problem local to their network?

Comment: How recently has the DNS changed? What is the TTL? What was the TTL before the change?

Comment: TTL is 3 hours. DNS was set up months ago and I think they didn't have a problem when first set up. 48 hrs ago CName for www was added (previously it was pointing straight to the server IP using an A record).

Comment: Which domain are they having trouble with? (For me, `www.` issues a 301 redirect to the main domain, which works fine.)

Comment: Thanks, yes I have a 301 set up in .htaccess for the www so that is as it should be. Neither main domain or www are working for them.

Comment: I'm stuck, then, but I'm no Server Fault professional. I'd suggest [edit]ing all the above clarifications into the question body itself, rather than leaving them buried in the comments. (Don't do it as "edit to add" notes: that's just messy. Simply incorporate all the information into a rewritten question.)

Answer (score 0):

Ask your client to run the nslookup command via command prompt or terminal on their machine to check if the DNS is resolving properly. If that fails, you could get them to run a tracert/traceroute to your site.

It could be something simple like your shared hosting provider blocking their IP for invalid login attempts if they are trying to log into FTP/IMAP and failing.